# How do I debug code in production org?

Tags: apex, trigger

Ok, I am having some issues in my code in production but not in dev org. I would like to add some debug statments and check the values in my trigger class in production but unfortunatley I know that we should not add statements in production. How do I debug values in production ?

Comment: if it is not reproducible in developer org, then create a new full copy/ partial sandbox and debug in that

Comment: Adding to the above, since you cannot change your code to add debug statements in the production directly, you need to add the debug statements in sandbox and deploy the code to prod to troubleshoot. There is an idea for the ask you have. See https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l049AAA

Answer (score 3):

This is an ideal use case for [Checkpoints](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm&type=5). Open the Developer Console, open the class or trigger that you'd like to examine, and click in the gutter (the left side of the line numbers) to set a checkpoint. Execute your code (e.g. save a record, click a button on a VF page, whatever), and then go back to the Developer Console. You'll see an entry in the Checkpoints tab that snapped an instance of your runtime at that Checkpoint. This allows you to examine all variables in memory at that point. This is far more useful than using debug statements, as you can see exactly the state of the system without having to wade through hundreds of thousands of lines of code.